# Slicing a numpy array into windows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a 400x400 image and I converted it to NumPy array. Now I need to crop this NumPy array of 8x8x50x50 slices. I mean, 64 slices each one should be 50x50.

For clarifying my situation I am giving one other example that is similar to my situation. I created an array that consists of 100 numbers and I need to get slices of it like in the photo. As you can see each row split to 5 and each cell column has 10 values in it.

How can split like that if I have a 400x400 NumPy array?

[image]

Comment: THe newest version, `1.20` has a https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view function.  A similar function has been cited in previous "moving window" answers (but imported from another package).

Comment: Have you searched SO [numpy] for other windowing, moving-window, or other related questions?

Comment: Have you tried using `np.reshape`?